# OKHTTP error "Unable to resolve host "...": No address associated with hostname"

Tags: android, okhttp

Has anyone encountered such an error lately? For three months the application worked correctly, but today okhttp has stopped connecting to any url. What could be the problem? I didn't change any code, only updated versions of dependencies.

This is my okhttp dependencies:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.8.0'
implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.8.0"
```

Also I tried to use these settings in Manifest:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
android:allowClearUserData="true">
```

but it didn't help.

I would be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your internet connection is on and Internet Permission

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Yes, these settings are set

Answer (score 0):

That's a DNS failure. Can you reach the site in a web browser like Chrome?